# Transfer blockchain from PC to Mac

Tags: blockchain, wallet, mac

I have a bitcoin wallet on my PC  but I just recently downloaded the MAC version of it.  I would like to initialize it with the blockchain from my PC so that I don't have to download it all over again.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory

Copy over your `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin` directory to `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`

Your AppData directory should be:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (XP)

C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista and 7)
```

If not, you can always run `explorer %APPDATA%\Bitcoin` in Command Prompt (Super-R, type `cmd`, hit "Run") to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to avoid people missing the key information about the wallet and blockchain - one is very private information and one is public information.  In copying as said here: [How to transfer only the blockchain to a friend's computer?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10787/how-to-transfer-only-the-blockchain-to-a-friends-computer)

> "To be more specific, you need to transfer the blocks and the chainstate directory. Don't transfer the database directory as it may contain remains from wallet.dat such as private keys. – rumpus"