# How to transfer only the blockchain to a friend's computer?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

After installing the bitcoin client (Qt) a friend got interested as well. He doesn't have as fast an internet connection, though, so I thought of burning some DVDs with the blockchains for him to have.

I saw [this question on how to transfer blockchain from PC to Mac](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/transfer-blockchain-from-pc-to-mac) and the solution was to copy the whole "Bitcoin" folder. However, that folder also contains MY wallet as well (which I definitely do not want my friend to have, even if encrypted).

So I'd like to know, which folder(s) and/or files do I need to copy, minimally, so he needs to get as few blocks over the network as possible?
If it's too much of a hassle, most probably I'll suggest him to use multibit or electrum instead :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Transfer everything except wallet.dat and the database folder.

Comment: To be more specific, you need to transfer the `blocks` and the `chainstate` directory. Don't transfer the `database` directory as it may contain remains from wallet.dat such as private keys.

Comment: The first comment is technically a "clearer" answer because it provides instructions in the affirmative (i.e. "copy only X and Y") instead of via negation (i.e. "copy everything except "L" and "M") - since the second set of instructions the user only knows what to copy by inference. However both are technically correct! Just a note for future answers and interested readers.

Comment: What about tx index on running wallet ? I suppose it will result in corrupted index, since the copying will run for hours anyway