# How do I copy the blockchain to a separate computer running Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm running bitcoin-qt 0.8.6 on a different computer that has the whole blockchain downloaded. I tried putting all the blk.dat files and the index from that computer  the blocks folder in bitcoin-qt v.10 on a separate computer but it wouldn't load. I tried reindexing it but it still wouldn't load. I'm not sure if the chainstate is related to the process because I tried placing the original in the new bitcoin qt application support folder but it would cause it to crash before opening or everything would be erased upon opening.

I'm running OSX Mavericks on the original computer and Yosemite on the new one.

Comment: @valkyrie ! Since bitcoin-qt is such a complex piece of software that the easiest answer to your question is: can't you let it run the usual way of downloading the blockchain per se ? Another point is: do you really have to run different versions of the software ?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10787/516

Comment: The answer to the linked thread above fully applies since the blockchain doesn't care what architecture or operating system that is running it **in terms of reading the core data directory**. See this useful post: https://bitzuma.com/posts/moving-the-bitcoin-core-data-directory/