# After a long connection to the wallet, it offers to reinstall blocks and synchronize all Bitcoin core blocks

Tags: bitcoin-core

1)I installed bitcoin core on an ssd drive. Some time did not include it, a month after the inclusion of bitcoin core when you start the application with ssd asks to re-download all the blocks, the path is correct , and the folder has already downloaded the blocks. I don't understand, my old wallet can't download or wants to download the resulting blocks while offline. Please help to understand.                                      2) If I installed a portable ssd drive I can connect it to any device and use the wallet and funds on it? In such an attempt, it requires downloading blocks again[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is a duplicate of that in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/83799/13866 - if that is also *your* question, you should have edited more information into your original question rather than add a duplicate question. Edited questions get pushed to the top of the front page, consequently there is no advantage to cluttering the website with multiple copies of the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The restart after moving data to a new machine might be because some program data is stored in the Windows registry (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Bitcoin\Bitcoin-Qt) which you might have left behind on a conventional HDD.

In particular the path to the data directory is stored in the registry. However simply the absence of any bitcoin key in the registry may be enough to convince Bitcoin core that it is running for the first time.

---

You can copy the blockchain data from an old install over the data directory created by a new install, so you can prevent the new install downloading the data you have already downloaded.

See [How to transfer only the blockchain to a friend's computer?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10787/13866)