# What files do I need to copy to a new computer to prevent having to sync with the network?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, database

I think this used to be the `blk0001.dat` file, but it seems that the block chain is now (since version ?) moved to the `blocks/` folder, containing a lot of `blk*` files, as well as an `index` file and multiple `rev*` files.

What files do I have to copy to a new machine if I want it to be synced up?

I know I will have to run with `-rescan` the first time after I changed the block chain files. And I know that the blocks are not verified (but they come from another machine I own, so there are no trust issues).

Please mention the current version number in your answer to not confuse people if the file configuration would change over time.

Comment: I believe this question http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/transfer-blockchain-from-pc-to-mac asks something very similar...

Comment: Not very similar. I don't want to move my whole setup, only the minimum block chain files. Also, a recent update changed the whole folder organisation.

Comment: In that case, you may be interested in a very similar question I asked http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10787/how-to-transfer-only-the-blockchain-to-a-friends-computer
Be warned, though: for what I read, most of the time spent when importing the blockchain is in validating all the entries - even after you'd copied the files, you'd still have to wait several hours...

Comment: @JoePineda, the blocks are not verified when you import them from another computer. The block chain is just scanned for transaction outputs of your addresses.

Comment: @StevenRoose Depends on what you mean by 'import'. If you copy just the block files (the contents of the blocks/ directory), they will be verified as if they were received from network. If you only copy the chainstate/ directory as well, there resulting state is already known and nothing will (need to) happen.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory

This might be of some help.I followed that and successfully moved the files from C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\ to E:\BitcoinData.

Just cut and paste the whole content of from the Bitcoin folder (C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin) and set the new target as

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=d:\BitCoinData and that is assuming you have bitcoin Qt installed in your C: drive.Change the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With the time between transactions, it currently can't be done.  The closest you can do is ( on windows ) copy the contents of (boot drive):\documents and settings(user)\application data\Bitcoin on Linux systems /home/(user)/.bitcoin
I am not fluent on Mac systems so no idea where it is stored there.

The entire contents contain the block chain, peers, your wallet and status of confirmation of transactions.  It will still try and re-sync even with these files, but at least you will not have to depend on network traffic to get it.